# Create a rule on URL Rewrite on this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, url-rewriting

How do I create a rule on URL Rewrite on IIS for change URL from Original URL to Final URL ?

`Original URL: [http://localhost:3030/POSMobileREST/POSService.svc/POSMobileREST/]`

`Final URL: [http://localhost:3030/POSMobileREST/]`

I tested on IIS6.2 on win8 and VS2012 and it still doesn't work.

**Sample :** 
Pattern : ^POSMobileREST/(.*)$
Action Type : Rewrite
Rewrite URL : POSService.svc/{R:1}

Comment: See sample on top again.